# Mongoose - Finding an item in subdocument array together with the whole total in that array

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a Shop collection with a document like this:

```
{
  _id:'xyz'
  sales:[
    {
      _id:'aaa'
      productId:'ppp',
      quantity: 3
    },
    {
     _id:'bbb'
     productId:'qqq'
     quantity: 4
   },
  ]
}
```

When i query an element in sales array (_id:'aaa') i need to get its quantity and the sum of quantity in the whole sales array
ie quantity:3,
   totalQuantity: 7

Same wise, when i query another element (_id:'bbb') i need to get quantity: 4, totalQuantity: 7

I have tried using aggregate, as follows:

```
Shop.aggregate([
        {$match: {'_id': ObjectId('xyz'),'sales._id':ObjectId('aaa')}},
        {$group: {
          _id: "$_id",
          totalQuantity: {
            "$sum": {
              "$sum": "$sales.quantity"
            }
          }
        }
 ])
```

But this doesn't work.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the totalQuantity using [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/).

We can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to find the required item, and access the quantity.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hRXARVfot8C)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: "xyz"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      totalQuantity: {
        $sum: "$sales.quantity"
      },
      quantity: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$sales",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this._id",
              "aaa"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      quantity: {
        $sum: "$quantity.quantity"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This will give the following result for the "aaa" value:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "xyz",
    "quantity": 3,
    "totalQuantity": 7
  }
]
```

And for a not found value, the quantity will be 0:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "xyz",
    "quantity": 0,
    "totalQuantity": 7
  }
]
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly, but I would like to understand this.
(1) Why do we put `$sum: "$quantity.quantity"`? What does this first `$quantity` stands for here?

Comment: The first quantity field (you can use another field name)  is the result of filter in the project stage, filter returns an array. So I overwrite that quantity field with addFields with the value of   `$sum: "$quantity.quantity"`.
Check this playgroud, I removed the last stage so that you can understand better. https://mongoplayground.net/p/Buqpeoi9Vjy

Comment: @Amani it would be better to ask a new question. If this question solves your original question, can you please mark it as answer? Mixing another question in a question is not a good idea.

Comment: @sulaymanSah Okay... I'm asking it now as a new question. I have accepted your answer. It really works

Comment: @Amani wait, it looks simple, I will try to help here, please wait.

Comment: @Amani I guess this solves your new question: https://mongoplayground.net/p/7gSlj8zJgz2

Comment: It woks like charm. You've saved a thousand lives. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214865/discussion-between-amani-and-suleymansah).